# Heading not moving to the center and responsive design issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-heading

I am trying to move the heading 'Education' to the center of the web page and facing an issue in doing so.

At the same time I am also working on the responsive design of this section where I have the image on top and the text below it. Can anyone help me out in resolving these issues?

The HTML and CSS code have been added below.

Thank you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.education-sec {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.education-width {
  max-width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.education-sec h1 {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.education-info {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.education-info p {
  font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Segoe UI, Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  line-height: 1.6;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.ed-under-line h1 {
  -webkit-text-decoration: #f57e3a solid underline;
  text-decoration: #f57e3a solid underline;
  -webkit-text-underline-position: under;
  text-underline-position: under;
}

.ed-img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40%;
}

.ed-img .bw_image {
  margin-left: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="education">
  <div class="education-sec">
    <div class="education-width">
      <div class="ed-under-line">
        <h1>Education</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="ed-img">
        <img class="bw_image" src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/500/442/354/outrun-vaporwave-hd-wallpaper-thumb.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="education-info">
        <p> XYZ University
          <br> M.Sc
          <br> Jan 21 - Sep 22</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using display: table ?

Comment: I was trying to work towards the responsive design and hence I added that line.

Comment: Hi Bumblebee, welcome to SO! You have quite some work cut out for you. If you want to go really responsive, you will need to loose ALL fixed units using 'px'. Use either 'rem' or 'em' instead. From now on, ONLY use 'px' units for borders, lines, shadow, etc. Google for 'CSS relative units'. Also distinguish between mobile, tablet and desktop devices (both 'portrait' and 'landscape' mode). Centering a header is the least of your problems...

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm new to CSS and will consider this practice when writing the code from now on!